# How to fix an error inserting csv data in Snowflake

Tags: sql, python-3.x, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data from csv file to a database using python with following code

```
file=open('C:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\Test\\csv_data_20181115.csv')
csv_data = csv.reader(file)
mydb = snowflake.connector.connect(
user=user,
password=password,
account=account,
database=database,
)

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(pivot, pivot_values)' ' VALUES({})'.format(row))

# close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_csv.py", line 26, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test_table_test(pivot, pivot_values)' ' VALUES({})'.format(row))
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py", line 550, in execute
    errvalue)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 97, in errorhandler_wrapper
    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, errorclass, errorvalue)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 73, in default_errorhandler
    done_format_msg=errorvalue.get(u'done_format_msg'))
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 58 unexpected '['.
syntax error line 1 at position 96 unexpected ']'.
```

When I print(row)
My data look as follows.

```
['pivotValues', 'pivotValues_stripped']
['urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:134971656', '134971656']
['urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:135043976', '135043976']
['urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:135249746', '135249746']
```

How can I insert data without these brackets ?

Comment: Note: Your code is going to copy the CSV headers into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(pivot, pivot_values)' ' VALUES({1},{2})'.format(row[0],row[1]))
```

Edit: 
without `.format()`

```
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(pivot, pivot_values)' ' VALUES('+str(row[0])+','+str(row[1])+')')
```

Comment: If it is a database prepared statement, you shouldn't use `.format` anyway

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have added an edit without use of `.format()`

Comment: String concantenation should be avoided always in SQL statements... If anything, I doubt both columns are even needed, as the second is just a subset of the first